# Determinant of integer lattice basis of `$L=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n): a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0\}$`

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

> **Question:** Suppose $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ is
>   an integer basis for the lattice
>   $$L=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n:
> > a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0\},$$ where the
>   $a_i$ are fixed nonzero integers. Is
>   the volume $V(P)=\det(L)$ (see [this](http://numbertheoryreadinggroup.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/geometry-of-numbers-lecture-2-determinant-of-the-lattice-and-the-fundamental-parallelepiped-lee/) for a proof that they are equal) of its
>   fundamental parallelotope
>   $P=\{t_1v_1+\cdots+t_{n-1}v_{n-1}
> > \mid t_i\in[0,1)\}$ necessarily equal
>   to
>   $$\frac{\sqrt{a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2}}{\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}?$$

I used the case $n=3$ along with [Minkowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) (in the [geometry of numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers)) to solve the following [Miklos problem](http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~mmaroti/schweitzer/schweitzer-2000-eng.pdf) from 2000:

> Let $a<b<c$ be positive integers.
>   Prove that there exist integers
>   $x,y,z$, not all zero, such that
>   $ax+by+cz=0$ and $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)\le
> > 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{c}$, and show
>   that the constant $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$
>   cannot be improved.

However, I was only able to find a brute force proof for this special case (see lemma 1 in my AoPS post [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2471417#p2471417)), and I'm not sure if it's as easy for larger values of $n$.

But I'm pretty sure this should be true in general (I've tried several cases for $n=4$ and $n=5$), so I would appreciate it if someone could give a (clean?) proof, reference, or counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: Without loss of generality the gcd is $1$.  Then ${\bf Z}^n$
contains the direct sum $L_1$ of $L$ with ${\bf Z}\cdot(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$
with index $A := a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2$.  Thus a fundamental parallelotope
for $L_1$ has volume $A$.  But this volume is the product of the
corresponding volumes for $L$ and ${\bf Z}\cdot(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.
The latter volume is $A^{1/2}$; hence the former is $A / A^{1/2} = A^{1/2}$,
**QED**.


Comment: Again, wlog gcd is 1. Take a fundamental parallelotope of $L$ and add a vector $v_n$ to obtain a f.p. of ${\mathbb Z}^n$. Then the endpoints of $v_n$ lie in the ``neighboring'' affine hyperspaces parallel to $L$, and the distance between them is exactly $1/\sqrt{a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2}$. 

Comment: More generally: suppose $L_0$ is a lattice *primitively* embedded in
${\bf Z}^n$; that is, if $L_0$ contains $mv$ for some nonzero $m\in\bf Z$
and $v \in {\bf Z}^n$ then $L_0$ contains $v$.  Let $L \subset {\bf Z}^n$
consist of the integer vectors orthogonal to every vector in $L_0$.
Then the fundamental parallelotopes of the lattices $L_0$, $L$
have the same volume.  Victor's question is the special case when
$L_0$ is the rank-$1$ lattice ${\bf Z}\cdot(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.


Answer (score 1):

I borrowed a few books; it turns out the material provided in comments to the answer is not in print in many places. One is a book I have, Lattices and Codes by Wolfgang Ebeling, on page 5 in the second edition. In turn, he refers to [Looijenga and Peters (1981)](https://eudml.org/doc/89474), who devote section 2 of their article to lattices, the particular result is on page 154. I lost that link, hold on.

[image]
[image]