# Relating the shortest vector of a lattice to the orthogonal complement of the lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

By a *lattice* we mean sub-lattice of $\mathbb{Z}^n \cap V$, where $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. We say that a lattice $\Lambda$ is *primitive* if a basis of $\Lambda$ can be extended to form a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

For a given lattice $\Lambda$, define its *orthogonal complement* $\Lambda^\ast$ by

$$\displaystyle \Lambda^\ast = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n : \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0 \text{ for all } \mathbf{y} \in \Lambda\}.$$

It is known that if $\Lambda$ is primitive, then $\det(\Lambda) = \det(\Lambda^\ast)$.

Suppose that we are given a lattice $\Lambda$, contained in a proper subspace $V \subset \mathbb{Q}^n$. Suppose that we know have an explicit basis for $\Lambda^\ast$. Do we then have any control over the length of the shortest vector in $\Lambda$? Is there any way to explicitly control the length of the shortest basis vector of $\Lambda$ given data from $\Lambda^\ast$?

Comment: (probably better to use a name other than "dual lattice" which usually means something else . . .)

Comment: I changed "dual lattice" to "orthogonal complement", since as Noam said, the former has a different meaning; and indeed, when I first read this post, I blipped over the displayed equation and assumed that $\Lambda^*$ was the dual, i.e., $$\{\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^n:\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{Z} \text{ for all }\boldsymbol{y}\in\Lambda\}.$$ I hope you don't mind the edit

Comment: @JoeSilverman Silverman I am aware of using the term "dual lattice" to refer to $\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n : \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, but Browning uses "dual lattice" to refer to the orthogonal complement, so I was following his convention.

Comment: What is the Browning reference?

Comment: Do you still assume that $\Lambda$ is primitive in your question?  Otherwise for any positive integer $m$,  $\Lambda$ and $m\Lambda$ (or any lattice on the subspace spanned by $\Lambda$)  have the same orthogonal complement in $\mathbb Z^n$, you probably cannot have any control on the length of the shortest vectors of $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Cassels, *Rational Quadratic Forms*. On page 138, Corollary 1 says the smallest absolute value of the quadratic form is no larger than
$$ \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^{(n-1)/2} \; |d|^{1/n} $$
You use the Gram determinant you have for $d,$ and the relevant $n$ is the dimension of your orthogonal lattice.

The translation to lattices should not change much, maybe a constant multiple.

Not really a change of subject, some years ago I was answering a question and got very frustrated at correctly finding ANY basis for the orthogonal lattice to a given one. It turned out that, given a few ($k$) rows $B$ such that $B$ can be completed to an integer unimodular matrix, we find a square unimodular integer matrix $W$ (by successive elementary matrix product) such that $BW$ is the first few rows of an identity matrix. Then a basis is given by the $n-k$ right columns of $W,$ and one possible completion of $B$ to an integer unimodular matrix is just $W^{-1}$

Comment: related questions/answers  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103152/    
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392683/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456368/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions-ii
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488074/basis-for-the-kernel-of-linear-map-for-linear-diophantine-equation-in-three-vari/2488307#2488307
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045647/consider-the-equation-27x-14y-10z-1-give-parameterized-solutions-for-all/3045778#3045778

Comment: This is a nice result when the dimension of the orthogonal complement is larger than the dimension of the original lattice, but unfortunately in the case I am interested in they are equal. Can one say anything about lower bounds?